# Error: 'multiverse' invalid + Error: 'universe' invalid

Tags: apt, add-apt-repository

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11

USER root

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository multiverse
RUN add-apt-repository universe
```

I am getting this error:

> Error: 'multiverse' invalid
> The command '/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository multiverse' returned a non-zero code: 1

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I apparently solved it by doing this:

```
RUN sed -i "/^# deb.*multiverse/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i "/^# deb.*universe/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Instead  of this:

```
RUN add-apt-repository multiverse
RUN add-apt-repository universe
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much Alexander Mills, I had the same problem and I was able to solve it on my system (Q4OS 3.10.3) with:

```bsh
sudo sed -i "/^# deb.*multiverse/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i "/^# deb.*universe/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

But im still facing this problem

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1219608)